# Problems with sending post variables with php curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying search products with curl on this page `http://212.202.102.92/abcrestore/search.aspx` but with same problems.

First of all I am trying to save cookies and find post variables...viewstate, eventarget, and then I use them with curl

Problem is that I have got no result or better said I have all result. 
I think problem is with post variables and cookies, but I have no idea what is wrong (maybe  all code is wrong??)

Search examples: CAS Number: 1631-26-1, 4814-74-8.

```
// headers
$header[] = "Host: 212.202.102.92";
$header[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1";
$header[] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: windows-1250,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 115";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";

$fp=fopen('abcr-temp.html','a');
fclose($fp);
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
$fp=fopen('abcr-temp.html','w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://212.202.102.92/abcrestore/product_information.aspx?product_id=1890&second_id=1890&nav=search');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//set cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/abcrcookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$html = file_get_contents('abcr-temp.html');
// find post variables
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$matches_lastfocus);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$matches_eventargument);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__PREVIOUSPAGE" id="__PREVIOUSPAGE" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$matches_previouspage);
//preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$matches_eventvalidation);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$matches_viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$matches_viewstateencrypted);
$postArray['__LASTFOCUS'] = $matches_lastfocus[1];
$postArray['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$btnSuchen';
$postArray['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = $matches_eventargument[1];
$postArray['__VIEWSTATE'] = $matches_viewstate[1];
$postArray['__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'] = $matches_viewstateencrypted[1];
$postArray['__PREVIOUSPAGE'] = $matches_previouspage[1];
$postArray['ctl00$ddlLanguage'] = 'en';
//$postArray['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $matches_eventvalidation[1]);
$postArray['ctl00$txtUserName'] = '';
$postArray['ctl00$txtPassword'] = '';
$postArray['ctl00$hfPassword'] = '';
$postArray['ctl00$edtBezeichnung'] = '';
$postArray['ctl00$edtArtikelnr'] = '';
$postArray['ctl00$edtSummenformel'] = '';
$postArray['ctl00$edtCAS'] = '541-59-3';
$postArray['ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1ATI'] = '0';

$postvars = "";
foreach($postArray as $key=>$value) { $postvars .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$postvars = rtrim($postvars ,'&');

$fpp=fopen('abcr-tempp.html','a');
fclose($fpp);

$ch = curl_init();
$fpp=fopen('abcr-tempp.html','w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://212.202.102.92/abcrestore/search.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/abcrcookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fpp);
//execute post
$output = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fpp);
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: The contents of the website are protected by copyright. Copying or reproducing (including printing out on paper) the entire website or parts of this website, will only be permitted for the purpose of submitting an order to ABCR or for using this website as a purchasing resource. Any other use of the materials or information available on this website – including reproduction, onward sale, change and publication for a purpose other than the one named above – is forbidden..... its there for a reason

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: if this post is against any rules please close it, but only what i want is chance to search on this page. It will be much easier for me if i would be able send search variable (cas num) with one click, when i am searching for source company. I am sorry.

Comment: i got that from there site...by all means screenscrapp but at least use a forged referrer and useragent ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$postvars = "";
foreach($postArray as $key=>$value) { $postvars .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$postvars = rtrim($postvars ,'&');
```

You're better off building your query string with [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$postvars = http_build_query($postArray);
```

It'd be a good idea to check the output of `print_r($postArray)` as well, to ensure you're sending the correct variables:

```
print_r($postArray);
```